# NMaximize refuses the constraint set

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to run the following `NMaximize` code but I receive `warnings` that the constraint set is not right.

```
Clear[n, objFun1, constFun1, varFun1, params, infoStk, transfer, absorb, parameters]
n = 3;
SeedRandom[14];

objFun={
    a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] + 
    a[1, 2] t[2, 1] ν[2] +
    (a[1, 2] t[2, 1] + a[3, 2] t[2, 3]) ν[2]
        };
constFun={
     0 <= a[3, 1] &&
     0 <= t[1, 3] && 
     0 <= a[1, 2] && 
     0 <= t[2, 1] &&
     0 <= a[3, 2] &&
     0 <= t[2, 3] &&
     a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] <= ν[3] && 
     a[1, 2] t[2, 1] ν[2] <= ν[1] && 
     a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] + a[3, 2] t[2, 3] ν[2] <= ν[3] &&
     a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] == a[1, 2] t[2, 1] ν[2]&&
     τ[1] >=t[1, 3] &&
     α[3] >= a[3, 1] &&
     τ[2] >=t[2, 1] && 
     α[1] >= a[1, 2] &&
     τ[2] >= t[2, 1] + t[2, 3] &&
     α[3] >= a[3, 1] + a[3, 2]
        };
varFun={a[3, 1], t[1, 3], a[1, 2], t[2, 1], a[3, 2], t[2, 3]};
params = {infoStk, transfer, absorb} = {
    RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n],    
    RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n],     
    RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n]      
      };
parameters = 
  Flatten[Thread[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@ 
    Thread[Array[#, n] & /@ {ν, τ, α} -> params]];
NMaximize[{objFun, constFun}, varFun] /. parameters
```

I receive the `Warning` below:

> NMaximize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {a[1,2] t[2,1] ν[2]==a[3,1] t[1,3] ν[1],α[1]>=a[1,2],α[3]>=a[3,1],α[3]>=a[3,1]+a[3,2],τ[1]>=t[1,3],τ[2]>=t[2,1],τ[2]>=t[2,1]+t[2,3],0<=a[1,2],0<=a[3,1],0<=a[3,2],0<=t[1,3],0<=t[2,1],0<=t[2,3],a[3,1] t[1,3] ν[1]<=ν[3],a[1,2] t[2,1] ν[2]<=ν[1],a[3,1] t[1,3] ν[1]+a[3,2] t[2,3] ν[2]<=ν[3]}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables. >>

but a solution is also given:

```
{0.259219, {a[3, 1] -> 0.378963, t[1, 3] -> 0.0325724, 
  a[1, 2] -> 0.361699, t[2, 1] -> 0.0341271, 
  a[3, 2] -> 1.27311*10^-12, t[2, 3] -> 0.0256519}}
```

My concern is that this solution does not properly account for the constraints.

Comment: I suppose it's because of a syntax error in the definition of `constFun`.  There are also errors in the definition of `params`.

Comment: You need to check the actual code you posted then.  Quit the kernel, post the code (in the right order), and execute.

Comment: For instance, if you look at the end of the def. of `constFun`, it's fairly obvious that nothing following the last `&&` is a syntax error.

Comment: I think you need to define `n` and use `NMaximize[{objFun[[1]], constFun} /. parameters, varFun]`.

Comment: Yes, that and `/.parameters` needs to happen inside `NMaximize[...]`.  That's what the  warning was telling you.  And just one of the constraints is `False` when `n = 200` and that is because you end up testing that two numbers are equal when they are both approximately zero.  So those constraints are pretty much realized as best they can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the coding errors are fixed, the results satisfy the constraints (to what one would expect recognizing that there will be round-off error).

```
Clear[n, objFun1, constFun1, varFun1, params, infoStk, transfer, absorb, parameters]
n = 20;
SeedRandom[14];

objFun = {a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] + a[1, 2] t[2, 1] ν[2] + (a[1, 2] t[2, 1] + a[3, 2] t[2, 3]) ν[2]};
constFun = {0 <= a[3, 1] && 0 <= t[1, 3] && 0 <= a[1, 2] && 
    0 <= t[2, 1] && 0 <= a[3, 2] && 0 <= t[2, 3] && 
    a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] <= ν[3] && 
    a[1, 2] t[2, 1] ν[2] <= ν[1] && 
    a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] + a[3, 2] t[2, 3] ν[2] <= ν[3] &&
    a[3, 1] t[1, 3] ν[1] == a[1, 2] t[2, 1] ν[2] && 
    τ[1] >= t[1, 3] && α[3] >= a[3, 1] && τ[2] >= t[2, 1] && 
    α[1] >= a[1, 2] && τ[2] >= t[2, 1] + t[2, 3] && α[3] >= a[3, 1] + a[3, 2]};
varFun = {a[3, 1], t[1, 3], a[1, 2], t[2, 1], a[3, 2], t[2, 3]};
params = {infoStk, transfer, absorb} = {RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n], 
    RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n], RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, n]};
parameters = Flatten[Thread[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@ Thread[Array[#, n] & /@ {ν, τ, α} -> params]];
sol = NMaximize[{objFun[[1]], constFun} /. parameters, varFun]
(* {5.85114, {a[3, 1] -> 0.932464, t[1, 3] -> 0.298806,
              a[1, 2] -> 0.770256, t[2, 1] -> 0.361731, 
              a[3, 2] -> 2.03066*10^-9, t[2, 3] -> 0.0722319}} *)
```

And one can determine which if any of the constraints are not (exactly) satisfied:

```
constraints = (constFun /. And -> List)[[1]] /. parameters;
status = Select[Transpose[{constraints, 
  (constraints /. {Equal -> List, LessEqual -> List, GreaterEqual -> List}) /. sol[[2]],
  (constraints /. sol[[2]])}], ! #[[3]] &]
(* {{7 a[3, 1] t[1, 3] == 7 a[1, 2] t[2, 1], {1.95038, 1.95038}, False}} *)
```

Comment: Your clarification is very useful, giving me clues where to look when similar problems arise. Since I did not run the entire code, which is very large, I do not even know what other problems will emerge. Anyway, your answer was very satisfactory. `n` in the problem is about the dimension of the variables and hence changing it without the actual problem formulation should not affect the solution.